# Code for peak detection

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I want to calculate if a real-time signal pass some thresholds in the first step. In the first step, I want to detect if the real signal pass under those thresholds (in order to detect a peak in the signal). My Matlab code:

```
k=1;  
t = 1;
l=1;

for i =1:length(sm) //sm my signal.

    if (sm(i) > 0.25)
        first(k) = i;
        k = k+1;
        if (sm(i) > 0.5)

            second(t) = i;
            t =t +1;
            if (sm(i) > 0.75)

                third(l) = i;
                l = l+1;
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Example:

![enter image description here][1]

I want to calculate the times that the signal pass over and under the three thresholds `0.25`, `0.5`, `0.75` and to return those windows. Basically the three main peaks that I have in my example.

Basically what am I trying to do is to use fastsmooth function and findpeaks.

```
signalSmoothed = fastsmooth(sm,50); plot(signalSmoothed)
[max_pk1 max_pk2] = findpeaks(signalSmoothed);
find(max_pk1 >0.5)
inversex = 1.01*max(signalSmoothed) - signalSmoothed;
[min_pk1 min_pk2]  = findpeaks(inversex);
find(min_pk1 >0.5)
```

Which are the heuristics in order to take only the desired peaks? Moreover the depticted image is an offline example. Generally I want to perform the technique online.

EDIT: I wrongfully defined as peak my desired curve result which is the whole wave not just the max value.

Comment: Do you want to detect them all separately or must all the conditions be met to define this as a peak? Also have you looked at [`findpeaks`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/findpeaks.html)? If you hand draw a sample curve and mark which peaks you are interested in finding that would be helpful

Comment: All condition must be met. In my example I have only the pass over condition and I am trying to calculate the pass under condition. Yes  however findpeaks return many values since the signal contain a lot of local maxinum.

Comment: In that case your question is not at all clear, please provide sample input and output data, calculate it manually (e.g. by hand)

Comment: Actually I want to locate the whole three curves of the signal.

Comment: Mark on your chart, in a different color, which points you are trying to find.

Comment: I mark the three main curves in the signal I want to store.

Comment: And what does your chart have to do with your code? Where are these `0.25`, `0.5`, and `0.75` points for example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a solution to get the points where the signal `sm` passes the thresholds *0.25*, *0.50* and *0.75*. The points can be converted into windows inside the data-range and get stored in `W`. Finally we can plot them easily in the same figure. Note that we need to do some checks in the local function `getwindows` to handle special cases, for example when the window starts outside the data-range. The detection of windows inside another window is done in the `getwindowsspecial`-function.

*Here is the code:*

```
function peakwindow
% generate sample data
rng(7);
sm = 2*rand(1,25)-0.5;
sm = interp1(1:length(sm),sm,1:0.01:100*length(sm));

% get points
firstup    = find(diff(sm > 0.25)==1);
secondup   = find(diff(sm > 0.50)==1);
thirdup    = find(diff(sm > 0.75)==1);
firstdown  = find(diff(sm < 0.25)==1);
seconddown = find(diff(sm < 0.50)==1);
thirddown  = find(diff(sm < 0.75)==1);

% plot the result
figure; hold on;
plot(sm,'k')
plot(firstup,sm(firstup),'*')
plot(firstdown,sm(firstdown),'*')
plot(secondup,sm(secondup),'*')
plot(seconddown,sm(seconddown),'*')
plot(thirdup,sm(thirdup),'*')
plot(thirddown,sm(thirddown),'*')

% get windows
W1 = getwindows(firstup,firstdown);
W2 = getwindows(secondup,seconddown);
W3 = getwindows(thirdup,thirddown);

% get special window
WS = getwindowsspecial(W1,W3);

% plot windows
plotwindow(W1,0.25,'r');
plotwindow(W2,0.50,'r');
plotwindow(W3,0.75,'r');
plotwindow(WS,0,'b-');


function W = getwindows(up,down)
if length(up)>1 && length(down)>1 && up(1)>down(1)
    down(1)=[]; % handle case when window begins out of bounds left
end
if length(up)<1 || length(down)<1;
    W = []; % handle if no complete window present
else
    % concatenate and handle case when a window ends out of bounds right
    W = [up(1:length(down));down]';
end


function plotwindow(W,y,lspec)
for i = 1:size(W,1)
    plot(W(i,:),[y,y],lspec)
end


% get windows of U where there is a window of H inside
function W = getwindowsspecial(U,H)
W = []; % empty matrix to begin with
for i = 1:size(U,1) % for all windows in U
    if any(H(:,1)>=U(i,1) & H(:,1)<=U(i,2))
        W = [W;U(i,:)]; % add window
    end
end
```

*This is the result:*

[image: result1]

---

*To see that the handling works properly, we can plot the result when initialized with `rng(3)`:*

[image: result2]

Note that the window of *0.25* and *0.50* would start out of bounds left and therefore is not present in the plotted windows.

Comment: Finally I want to keep the window as in the depicted image I have updated. How can I do so?

Comment: @Matt you don't need the for-loop here. Try something along the lines of `firstup = diff(sm > 0.25)==1` etc and `firstdown = diff(sm > 0.25)==-1`

Comment: @Matt now if you want to add "getting the windows", which is a very unlcear notion but anyway, you can try `arrayfun(@(x)(sm(firstup(x):min(firstdown(x), end)), 1:numel(firstup), 'uni', 0)`

Comment: @Dan Thanks for the proposition. I thought first that it is just as easy as putting them together, but I saw that some checks are needed to handle special cases. That's why I used a local function to generate the window. If you have any improvements, please let me know.

Comment: How can I find the x-axis windows that both three condition are met?

Comment: This is stored in `W3`. This is the window where the signal is *>0.75* and therefore it is *>0.50* and *>0.25* as well.

Comment: In W3 it is stored the windows that the signal pass over the 0.75 values. How can I find the correspondant values in the same peak for the 0.25 and 0.5?

Comment: Finally I want to find the time- windows when the signal pass though both in ascending and descending order from values 0.25, 0.5, 0.75 not just when it passed from 0.75 only.

Comment: @snakeplissken  The other windows are stored in `W1` for *>0.25* and in `W2` for *>0.50*.

Comment: Yes indeed. I want to find when the three cases are met together. Thus my signal pass with ascending order 0.25, 0.5,  0.75 and simultaneously with descending order 0.75, 0.5, 0.25.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83099/discussion-between-matt-and-snake-plissken).