# Find overlapping between two lists in c#

Tags: c#, matlab, overlap

I have got a matlab code which calculates the overlap of two lists. In fact it check if a list H is inside another list U and keeps the window of list U where the list H is inside(at least one time). In fact U, H is index list of Nx2 size where in every point there two values for the begining index of the window and the end index of the window.  My code in matlab is:

```
function W = getwindowsspecial(U,H)
W = [];
for i = 1:size(U,1)
  if any(H(:,1)>=U(i,1) & H(:,1)<=U(i,2))
    W = [W;U(i,:)];
  end
end
```

For example U could be:

```
54  86
112 217
292 325
402 451
628 664
```

H could be:

```
129 214
297 321
406 447
637 664
```

and the result W is:

```
112 217
292 325
402 451
```

I want to convert that code to c#. My list U, H are as List>>. My correspondant function is the following:

```
 static List<int> getWindows(List<List<int>> list1, List<List<int>> list2)
    {
        List<int> list3 = new List<int>();

        for (int index = 0; index < list1[0].Count; index++) { 

        }

            return list3;
    }
```

What should I fill in my function in order to work as the Matlab one?

EDIT: In this code I add the limits for the first and the second list. How is it possible to add those limits to Tuple instead of list of lists?

```
        List<List<int>> first = new List<List<int>>();
        List<List<int>> second = new List<List<int>>();
        first.Add(upFirst); first.Add(downFirst);
        second.Add(upSecond); second.Add(downSecond);

        getWindows(first, second);
```

upFirst and upSecond contains all the left limits for the first and second list and downFirst and downSecond contains all the right limits for the first and the second lists. I tried to use the following code to do my job:

```
 for (int index = 0; index < upFirst.Count; index++){

            first.Add(new List<int> { upFirst[index], downFirst[index] });

 }

 for (int index = 0; index < upSecond.Count; index++){

           second.Add(new List<int> { upSecond[index], downSecond[index]});

  }
  List<List<int>> lista = GetWindows(first, second);
```

This is what I tried in order to add as tuples. However using as the function of 
@M. Nasser Javaid I got NULL as result. The input that I provide the list of lists first and second are:[image]

Comment: Your output is not clear. How it is the intersection of U & H?

Comment: It is not exactly overlap, in fact it checks if in every window of U there is a window of H and returns in case of true the window of U.

Comment: Should `H(:,1)<=U(i,2)` not be `H(:,2)<=U(i,2)`?

Comment: Basically it just checks if there is a window `H` in `U`. Therefore we check if a window in `H` has a starting point within a window of `U`. If there is a starting point, the window of `U` is added to the output of `W`. The code is taken from an answer where `U` is always a subset of `H`.

Comment: `112 217` is in the range of H so you add it into separate list? right?

Comment: YEs exactly this is what I want finally.

Comment: The code is from my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31342085/5024726

Comment: Why is `628 664` not in the output since `H(:,1)` contains `637` which falls in the range. Also why is there an `H(:,2)`? If it's irrelevant to the question, maybe remove it?

Comment: Yes Matt the matlab code is from your answer in this post. I dont want H to have the exact boundary with U as in case of right boundary 664. @Dan

Comment: @christosh then `H(:,1)<=U(i,2)` should have a `<` rather than a `<=` surely?

Comment: Yea @Dan you are right, however this is a minor issue. My prob is how to check inside a loop if a window of the first list contains windows of the second list.

Comment: @Dan The Matlab-code returns `628 664` as well, I just tested that. @OP: To give you the correct answer we need to know because of what criteria the last entry should not be in `W`then. Please edit your question to clarify this circumstance. Additionally you ask *«...in order to work as the Matlab one?»* and that's not what you actually want.

Comment: Why not create a dll in Matlab and call the dll from c#.  Will be much more efficient.

Comment: :D come on this is not an answer! @jdweng

Comment: @christosh What should be the output after editing of your question according input from screen shot?

Comment: I should got the first two windows 3-25 and 27-34 and put it in the returned list.

Comment: @christosh `3-25` is not starting in the range of `H` because `3` is lesser than `12` similarly `34` is out of range because your `H` ends with `31`. Now scenario has been changed.

Comment: @Nasser list H has several windows 12-19 and 28-21 and first window is inside the window of U which is  3-25 and the second window of L is inside the second window of U which is 27-34.

Comment: @christosh: Did you try the solution I posted? I developed it test-first, so I do have a solution with a unit-test for it (based on your sample data) if you'd like :)

Comment: Yes it is.  Matlab comes with a dll compiler.  We use it at work all the time and call it from c# code.  Lot of people use the dll compiler because matlab is more efficient than c#with  complex math processing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this please. According to given scenario we need numbers from U which are in the range of H so they are...

```
public void Test()
    {
        var listU = new List<List<int>>
        {
            new List<int> {54, 86},
            new List<int> {112, 217},
            new List<int> {292, 325},
            new List<int> {402, 451},
            new List<int> {628, 664}
        };
        var listH = new List<List<int>>
        {
            new List<int> {129, 214},
            new List<int> {297, 321},
            new List<int> {406, 447},
            new List<int> {637, 664}
        };
        GetWindows(listU, listH);
    }

static List<List<int>> GetWindows(List<List<int>> listU, List<List<int>> listH)
    {
        List<List<int>> list3 = new List<List<int>>();
        var startingOfH = listH.First()[0];
        var endOfH = listH.Last()[listH.Last().Count - 1];
        foreach (var num in listU)
        {
            var initial = num[0];
            var final = num[num.Count - 1];
            if (initial > startingOfH && final < endOfH)
            {
                list3.Add(num);
            }
        }
        return list3;
    }
```

Edit: 
If you want to use as Linq then use this

```
static List<List<int>> GetWindows(List<List<int>> listU, List<List<int>> listH)
    {
        var startingOfH = listH.First()[0];
        var endOfH = listH.Last()[listH.Last().Count - 1];
        return (from num in listU 
                let initial = num[0] 
                let final = num[num.Count - 1] 
                where initial > startingOfH && final < endOfH 
                select num).ToList();
    }
```

Edit 2:
Ignore initial value

```
static List<List<int>> GetWindows(List<List<int>> listU, List<List<int>> listH)
    {
        List<List<int>> list3 = new List<List<int>>();
        var startingOfH = listH.First()[0];
        var endOfH = listH.Last()[listH.Last().Count - 1];
        foreach (var num in listH)
        {
            var final = num[num.Count - 1];
            if (final > startingOfH && final < endOfH)
            {
                list3.Add(num);
            }
        }
        return list3;
    }
```

If you like Linq then

```
static List<List<int>> GetWindows(List<List<int>> listU, List<List<int>> listH)
    {
        var startingOfH = listH.First()[0];
        var endOfH = listH.Last()[listH.Last().Count - 1];
        return (from num in listH 
                let final = num[num.Count - 1] 
                where final > startingOfH && final < endOfH 
                select num).ToList();
    }
```

Comment: I got Null as a result. As an input I have listU, listH which contains two lists the first are the left limits of the window and in the second list the right limit of the window.

Comment: Yea the way I have created my lists is the opposite of yours. What if I have as an input  new List<int> {54, 112. 292, 402, 628}, new List<int>{86,217, 325, 451, 664};

Comment: But they are plan lists not `List<List<int>>`. Can you provide me both input `List<List<int>>`?

Comment: Yes I got the same result with you edit. However in my data it doesnt worked? What I am missing here?

Comment: @christosh You are getting output empty because there is no number pair in U which is in the range of H.

Comment: Ha now I got the point, we see the lists different. The first list has the windows 3-25, 27-34 and 35-38 while the second list has 12-19 and 28-31. 12-19 is inside 3-25 and 28-31 is inside 27-34. Thus I want to get the first two windows.

Comment: It depends on your input. If you swap `U` to `H` and `H` to `U` then you will of course get different output.

Comment: If I change the order in arguments List<List<int>> lista1 = GetWindows(second, first); I got 2 desired lists but the returned range is for the list H no the range for list U. I got as a result  12-19 and 28-31 instead of 3-25 and 27-24.

Comment: @christosh Do you want to get results from H now? the function will be changed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83190/discussion-between-christosh-and-m-nasser-javaid).

Answer (score 4):

You could do this with a few LINQ queries against the two lists. To make it read a little easier, I'll assume you have lists of tuples, i.e. `List<Tuple<int, int>>`s, rather than lists of lists.

```
var W = U.Where(u => H.Any(h => h.Item1 >= u.Item1 && h.Item1 <= u.Item2));
```

Note that this replicates the logic in your MATLAB sample, but doesn't give the results you specify in your sample. If you want to replicate the sample, change the second condition to `h.Item2 < u.Item2`, i.e. look at the end of the element from H, and require strict inequality.

---

**`Tuple`s vs `List`s**

If the `Tuple<int,int>`s feel strange, don't worry - they're really easy to construct:

```
var t = Tuple.Create(2, 3);
```

Depending on where you get your data from, this shouldn't be troublesome. If, however, you already have your data as `List<List<int>>`s, you can easily change the condition to use `h[0]` instead of `h.Item1` etc.

The main reason I suggest tuples is that they're going to be much more efficient, especially if you have many rows in your matrices `U` and `H`.

Comment: One last question Tomas, why to perform LINQ to Tuple and not in the List?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, but if you're asking why I use LINQ instead of a loop, it's because I think the code is easier to read. If you ask why Tuples are faster than Lists, it's (in as few words as possible) because they are fix-length, and therefore have very little overhead (Lists have any number of elements, and so every inner list must be able to hold 0-infinity of values, although you know you only need exactly two values...)